# javac -version not found by ionic, but it is in the path

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, path

The title says it all.

This is a similar question, but doesn't seem to be applicable here. [PhoneGap/Cordova "javac -version" not found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801562/phonegap-cordova-javac-version-not-found)

Here is an image of the issue I am having. I am kindof out of ideas on how to fix it. Has anyone encountered this before?

[image: javac inconsistency]

Answer (score 0):

Use "javac", not "javac -version".

Comment: javac -version can't be run without javac

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood what you were saaying?

Comment: I thought Ionic was trying to run a program called "javac -version", but that is not a program, that is a piece of commandline.  If I am mistaken, then Ionic must be using a different PATH then you when you start "javac -version".  Are you sure Ionic can be run under Mingw64?  Eg. JDK_HOME is defined with backslashes "\",  which have a different meaning in Unix environments.

Comment: Yeah, it can run using git bash, I have done it before on an old computer. Just to be sure I did try to run it on cmd, and that actually gave me a different error, though I suspect one is causing the other. Good thinking! On cmd it is saying gradle isn't installed or on the path (which it is sigh :()

Comment: In both instances it seems to be a PATH problem.  Does Ionic have a .rc or other config where its PATH would be set?